# Toggle screens bearing similar text fields

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, enums

I am learning dart and flutter programming. I am creating two screens: sign in and signup page but since they share the same code with just a few different code lines, i wanted to design one code and use an enum and if statement to make it look like two screens and then toggle them. However, when i first created this, i was using a macbook and iphone simulator. it worked well. However, when i sold the macbook off and got windows, i transfered the code to windows and now i am using android studio and android simulator. Unfortunately, I see i can switch from the sign in page to sign up page but can not go back to sign in page. Its like i can't toggle the screens anymore. Is there anyone who can get me out of this mess?

Below are the toggle method and screen methods. Let me know what i need to do. This is flutter

```
type here
```

```
`void switchFormState(String state) {
    _formKey.currentState?.reset();
    if (state == 'SignUp') {
      setState(() {
        authFormType = AuthFormType.signIn;
        //sign up
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        authFormType = AuthFormType.signUp;
        //sign in here
      });
    }
  }


List<Widget> buildButtons() {
    String switchButtonText, newFormState;

    if (authFormType == AuthFormType.signIn) {
      switchButtonText = 'Have no account? Create one';
      newFormState = 'Sign Up';
    } else {
      switchButtonText = 'Have an Account? Sign In';
      newFormState = 'Sign In';
    }
    return [
      TextButton(
          onPressed: (){
            switchFormState(newFormState);

          },
          child: Text(
            switchButtonText,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,
                color: Colors.black),
          ))
    ];
  }
```

type here

```
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because in `switchFormState` function you have compared  `if (state == 'SignUp')` but in **buildButtons** fun you have passed `newFormState = 'Sign Up';`

by changing `if (state == 'Sign Up')`inside your `switchFormState` will fix this.

Comment: Thank you Mr @abhishev-yadav. What a subtle yet powerful and keen observation!